Rplotly plot showing white viewer
Using getting started with rplotly guide, viewer pane shows white. how to get around with this? many thanks in advance.
install.packages("plotly")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
library(plotly)

set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point(aes(text = paste("Clarity:", clarity)), size = 4) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = cut, fill = cut)) + facet_wrap(~ cut)

ggplotly(p)


sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Rome
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rjson_0.2.21    scales_1.3.0    lubridate_1.9.3 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.1  
 [6] dplyr_1.1.4     purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.5     tidyr_1.3.1     tibble_3.2.1   
[11] tidyverse_2.0.0 plotly_4.10.4   ggplot2_3.5.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.5      remotes_2.5.0     htmlwidgets_1.6.4 devtools_2.4.5   
 [5] processx_3.8.4    lattice_0.22-6    callr_3.7.6       tzdb_0.4.0       
 [9] ps_1.7.6          vctrs_0.6.5       tools_4.4.0       crosstalk_1.2.1  
[13] generics_0.1.3    curl_5.2.1        parallel_4.4.0    fansi_1.0.6      
[17] pkgconfig_2.0.3   Matrix_1.7-0      data.table_1.15.4 desc_1.4.3       
[21] lifecycle_1.0.4   compiler_4.4.0    farver_2.1.2      munsell_0.5.1    
[25] httpuv_1.6.15     usethis_2.2.3     htmltools_0.5.8.1 yaml_2.3.8       
[29] lazyeval_0.2.2    urlchecker_1.0.1  later_1.3.2       pillar_1.9.0     
[33] crayon_1.5.2      ellipsis_0.3.2    rsconnect_1.2.2   cachem_1.1.0     
[37] sessioninfo_1.2.2 mime_0.12         nlme_3.1-164      tidyselect_1.2.1 
[41] digest_0.6.35     stringi_1.8.4     labeling_0.4.3    splines_4.4.0    
[45] fastmap_1.2.0     grid_4.4.0        colorspace_2.1-0  cli_3.6.2        
[49] magrittr_2.0.3    pkgbuild_1.4.4    utf8_1.2.4        withr_3.0.0      
[53] promises_1.3.0    bit64_4.0.5       timechange_0.3.0  httr_1.4.7       
[57] bit_4.0.5         hms_1.1.3         memoise_2.0.1     shiny_1.8.1.1    
[61] miniUI_0.1.1.1    viridisLite_0.4.2 mgcv_1.9-1        profvis_0.3.8    
[65] rlang_1.1.3       Rcpp_1.0.12       xtable_1.8-4      glue_1.7.0       
[69] pkgload_1.3.4     rstudioapi_0.16.0 vroom_1.6.5       jsonlite_1.8.8   
[73] R6_2.5.1          fs_1.6.4  


The code worked just fine for me... Maybe share your session info also

Hi Lucca, just added

This is a known issue with R 4.4.0 and affects all htmlwidget-based packages, not just plotly. An unofficial patched version of R 4.4.0 was released a few weeks ago to solve this issue.
